# How can I determine the transfer rate ?

Tags: asp.net

Can I determine from an ASP.NET application the transfer rate, i.e. how many KB per second are transferd?

Answer (score 3):

You can set some performance counters on ASP.NET.

See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/852720c8-7589-49c3-a9d1-73fdfc9126f0.mspx?mfr=true) for some examples.

Some specific ones that may help you figure out what you want are:

**Request Bytes Out Total**

The total size, in bytes, of responses sent to a client. This does not include standard HTTP response headers.

**Requests/Sec**

The number of requests executed per second. This represents the current throughput of the application. Under constant load, this number should remain within a certain range, barring other server work (such as garbage collection, cache cleanup thread, external server tools, and so on).

**Requests Total**

The total number of requests since the service was started.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of debugging tools you can use to check this at the browser.  It will of course vary by page, cache settings, server load, network connection speed, etc.

Check out http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/

Or if you are using Firefox, the FireBug add-in http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843